# Editing GPO Programmatically

Tags: windows, windows-xp, batch, group-policy, desktop-customization

I have a batch file that I'm using to update a large group of computers. This batch file works, for the most part. Where it fails is when the computer has been set up to "Disable Active Desktop" under User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Desktop -> Active Desktop. This is to say that when this feature is enabled I cannot make the changes I wish to make. I want to disable this if it has previously been enabled, then change the background, and finally return this setting back to its original state.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. "the computer has been set up to Disable Active Desktop", and you want to "disable these settings"? Meaning you want to disable "Disable Active Desktop", i.e. enable it again? If so, you should rephrase without the double negatives.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with editing GPO programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by changing this registry value: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoActiveDesktop` from 1 to 0.

Changing this key from within a batch file can be accomplished with the command: `reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\ /v NoActiveDesktop /d 0`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. After editing the registry key, it doesn't apply the changes inside of gpedit.

Comment: @davelupt: Also try modifying the value of `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoActiveDesktopChanges`.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out just a bit ago. I had to use another machine, edit the settings of gpedit.msc to reflect what I wanted. Copy the files located in C:\Windows\system32\GroupPolicy and then paste them on the machine I wanted to change. After doing that I could edit the registry and finally call xcopy again to revert the settings back. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Edit, do not attempt to do what I previously mentioned. Please view this page for a solution of how to move Group Policy settings across like machines: http://escapelogic.com/main/node/2 otherwise you may end up wasting a good bit of time.